# javascript alert message does not pop up, why?

Tags: javascript

this should work, I am just trying to contact a node and find out it's value.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function nadfunc() {
                var demoList = document.getElementById('eventsList');
                alert(var);
            }
            nadfunc();
        </script>

        <ul id="eventsList">
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>
                <a id="linkedItem" href="http://www.google.com">Linked List Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: Order matters. `<script>`s can execute before the `document` has finished loading. With the current order, the `<ul id="eventsList">` won't be available yet for `document.getElementById('eventsList')` to find it.

Comment: Also, do you mean to `alert(demoList);`?

Answer (score 9):

write

```
alert(demoList);
```

`var` is just a keyword, you have to use actual variable name.

Also, Your script block should be placed at the end of the page before closing body tag:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>    
        <ul id="eventsList">
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
            <li><a id="linkedItem" href="http://www.google.com">Linked List Item</a></li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function nadfunc() {
                var demoList = document.getElementById('eventsList');
                alert(demoList);
            }
            nadfunc();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LisaJenkins welcome to StackOverflow, you can accept my answer if you find it helpful http://stackoverflow.com/about